# How to open a gem source code with bundler in vim editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Trying to open a gem source code with `bundle open` command, [according to official documentation and instruction](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_open.html).

So, I `exported` editor like this in `.profile`:

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=vi
export EDITOR=vi
```

And try to open e.g. `rails` source code using console:

```
bundle open rails
```

and getting error `Could not locale Gemfile`

```
[ruby-2.1.1] 
[~/]
 $: rails -v 
Rails 4.0.3
[ruby-2.1.1] 
[~/]
 $: bundle -v 
Bundler version 1.5.3
[ruby-2.1.1] 
[~/]
 $: bundle open rails 
Could not locate Gemfile
[ruby-2.1.1] 
[~/]
 $:
```

What is missing in this steps ? How do open rails source code using bundler.

Comment: Run `bundle open ...` from a directory with a Gemfile containing that gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a gem called `qwandry`. With this you can run

```
qw qwandry
```

to open up the qwandry source code in your editor (also configurable with the `-e` parameter). It also knows how to load up python, perl and node packages.

Answer (score 21):

Do this from within a directory that contains a Gemfile:

```
vim `bundle show GEM_NAME`
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably better to set your preferred editor in your `.bash_profile`
and then just use `bundle open GEMNAME`

```
  export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim    # OR /usr/local/bin/subl
  bundle open whatever_gem
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bundler you need a Gemfile to manage your gems.

You can try to use this other gem to do this:

https://github.com/adamsanderson/open_gem